# SF novel I read from a series in the 1980's: Military "battle suits" in post-apocalyptic America

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic

I read this in grade school and cannot remember the name. The book I read was part of a series because I remember wanting to continue it, but could never find the proceeding books.

The story was about a military team that was trained to use large "battle suits" in a post-nuclear America. The story revolved around the leader of this team and his wife/girlfriend who were separated prior to the attack. I also remember the premise was the Soviet Union launched a surprise attack on the U.S. The rest of the story I can recall is just bits and pieces.

Has anyone ever read anything like this, and can you recall the name of the series?

Edit: Couple details I can remember:

- The battle suits apparantly roll because I remember them "rolling" across a desert of dusty area.
- The wife/girlfriend upon seeing a mushroom cloud from her stopped car on the interstate is immediately attacked by a stranger that is also watching the mushroom cloud. She was apparantly trained in self-defense by her military husband/boyfriend.

I will edit if I remember more.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good start. Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and see if you can edit in any more details.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[CADS from John Sievert](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821716417)
has the post-apocalyptic setting, Soviets and powered armor that charged from a rolling tank called the "Rhino."

Comment: Yes! That's it! This has literally been driving me nut for years! Thank you!